# Firebase storage image coming back blank

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I know I'm missing something simple, but I've spent hours trying to figure it out. All my code works and runs fine except there is no image. It is blank. Why?

```
func loadMembers4(completion: @escaping ([User]) -> ()) {
    var usersArray = [User]()
    ref.child("members").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for item in snapshot.children {
            if let snap = item as? FIRDataSnapshot {
                if let value = snap.value as? [String : Any] {
                    let birthday = value["birthday"] as! Int
                    let childParent = value["childParent"] as! String
                    let firstName = value["firstName"] as! String
                    let gender = value["gender"] as! String
                    let passcode = value["passcode"] as! Int
                    let profileImageUrl = value["profileImageUrl"] as! String

                    // get image

                    self.loadMemberProfilePict4(userProfileImageUrl: profileImageUrl, completion: { (userImage) in
                        let user = User(profilePhoto: userImage, userFirstName: firstName, userBirthday: birthday, userPasscode: passcode, userGender: gender, isUserChildOrParent: childParent)
                        usersArray.append(user)
                        usersArray.sort(by: {$0.birthday > $1.birthday})
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        completion(usersArray)
    })
}

func loadMemberProfilePict4(userProfileImageUrl: String, completion: @escaping (UIImage) -> ()) {
    var userImage = UIImage()
    let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: userProfileImageUrl)
    print(userProfileImageUrl)
    storageRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (imageData, error) in
        let profileImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
        userImage = profileImage!
    })
    completion(userImage)
}
```

And the `ViewDidLoad` method:

```
loadMembers4 { (usersArray) in
        print(usersArray.count)
        self.currentUserName = usersArray[1].firstName
        self.instructionsLabel.text = "Choose daily and weekly job assignments for \(usersArray[1].firstName)."
        self.userImage.image = usersArray[1].photo
    }
```

I know the image is getting fetched from Firebase because when I print `userProfileImageUrl` in the `loadMemberProfilePict4` function, it prints out the correct Firebase Storage location. But when I call it in the `ViewDidLoad`, the image shows up as blank. Nothing there.

Any ideas? Again, I'm sure it's something simple that I'm overlooking and just need a fresh pair of eyes to point it out. Thanks!

EDIT #1:

If I print out what's going on in the `loadMembersProfilePict4` method, it shows the following:

```
func loadMemberProfilePict4(userProfileImageUrl: String, completion: @escaping (UIImage) -> ()) {
    var userImage = UIImage()
    let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: userProfileImageUrl)
    print("UserProfileURL: ",userProfileImageUrl)       // returns 4 strings of https://firebasestorage.google... (all correct)

    storageRef.data(withMaxSize: 1024 * 1024) { (imageData, error) in
        print("ImageData: ",imageData ?? "no data found!")          // returns 21061 bytes, 7668 bytes, 44887 bytes, 8995 bytes (is this right?)

        let profileImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
        userImage = profileImage!
        print("UserImage: ",userImage.images ?? "no images found!")     // returns "no images found!"
    }
    completion(userImage)
}
```

So it would seem that somehow the image isn't getting loaded properly? I don't get it. I use this exact same code in another part of my project, and it loads the user images just fine. What is going on? Aargh! So frustrating.

Comment: if you move this statement :`completion(userImage)` after `userImage = profileImage!` , then see what is the behaviour, I think this will solve the problem

Comment: I tried that code already. It gives me a `fatal error: index out of range` error.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the completion handler in the 'loadMemberProfilePict4` method. Somehow it's not being called until it's too late... Because if I allow it to finish loading, it'll quickly cycle through all the images and then land on a random one...

Comment: where does the above error occur? and please check what is the value of `userImage` after this statement `userImage = profileImage!`?

Comment: Yes, when you call method which perform operation on firebase it's always async operation. So before operation completion your next code will execute. So move your code in completion block of loadMemberProfilePict4() method.

Comment: @3stud1ant3 error occurs in the `ViewDidLoad` method when I call `self.currentUserName = usersArray[1].firstname`.

Comment: @NishantBhindi, can u please give code example? I'm not sure exactly what you mean.

Comment: @3stud1ant3 I posted the printouts at different times of the function. As you can see, the images are there, and they are loading, but then somehow between when the storage retrieves `imageData` and turning it into `UIImage(data: imageData!), the information gets lost. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after spending the past two days trying to figure out a solution, I've come to the conclusion that for some reason Swift won't allow me to make embedded `@escaping` closures. I can create separate `@escaping` closures and they both work, but if I put one inside another, the second one won't execute properly.

So this is what I ended up doing:

**Function #1:** gets Firebase data for users, including a URL string for users' photo stored on Firebase Storage.

```
func loadMembers(completion: @escaping ([UserClass]) -> ()) {
    var usersArray = [UserClass]()
    ref.child("members").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for item in snapshot.children {
            if let snap = item as? FIRDataSnapshot {
                if let value = snap.value as? [String : Any] {
                    let birthday = value["birthday"] as! Int
                    let childParent = value["childParent"] as! String
                    let firstName = value["firstName"] as! String
                    let gender = value["gender"] as! String
                    let passcode = value["passcode"] as! Int
                    let profileImageUrl = value["profileImageUrl"] as! String

                    let user = UserClass(userProfileImageURL: profileImageUrl, userFirstName: firstName, userBirthday: birthday, userPasscode: passcode, userGender: gender, isUserChildOrParent: childParent)
                    usersArray.append(user)
                    usersArray.sort(by: {$0.birthday > $1.birthday})
                }
            }
        }
        completion(usersArray)
    })
}
```

**Function #2:** takes URL string from first function and uses it to load users' images from Firebase. This does not give me the complete array of images, however, as it loads them incrementally one at a time. Instead of giving me `count: 4`, it would give me `count: 1, count: 2, count: 3, count: 4`.

So when I would load the view controller, the images would cycle through each user before landing on the correct one. Not ideal.

```
// WORKS BEST, BUT IMAGES CYCLE THRU ALL USERS
func loadMemberProfilePict(userImageURL: String, userFirstName: String, userBirthday: Int, userPasscode: Int, userGender: String, userChildParent: String, completion: @escaping ([User]) -> ()) {
    let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: userImageURL)
    storageRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in
        let pic = UIImage(data: data!)
        let user = User(profilePhoto: pic!,
                        userFirstName: userFirstName,
                        userBirthday: userBirthday,
                        userPasscode: userPasscode,
                        userGender: userGender,
                        isUserChildOrParent: userChildParent)
        self.users.append(user)
        self.users.sort(by: {$0.birthday > $1.birthday})
        completion(self.users)
    })
}
```

**Function #3:** which leads to this function where I used a simple `'if'` statement to wait until all the users had been loaded before displaying them on the view.

In `ViewDidLoad`:

```
loadMembers { (usersArray) in
        var memberImageCount = 0

        for user in usersArray {
            self.loadMemberProfilePict(userImageURL: user.imageURL, userFirstName: user.firstName, userBirthday: user.birthday, userPasscode: user.passcode, userGender: user.gender, userChildParent: user.childParent, completion: { (usersIntermediateArray) in
                memberImageCount += 1
                if memberImageCount == usersArray.count {
                    self.users = usersIntermediateArray
                    self.userImage.image = self.users[3].photo
                    self.currentUserName = self.users[3].firstName
                    self.instructionsLabel.text = "Choose daily and weekly job assignments for \(self.users[3].firstName)."
                    self.navigationItem.title = self.users[3].firstName
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

I don't know if this is the best practice, but it's functional, and I hope it helps someone in the future who might have the same problem.

Comment: This is kind of like a poor man's escaping closure. Ha ha ha!

Answer (score 2):

> I simply put two line for userName and image of viewDidLoad() method into completion block of respective method. Remove that lines from viewDidLoad().

```
func loadMemberProfilePict4(userProfileImageUrl: String, completion: @escaping (UIImage) -> ()) {
    var userImage = UIImage()
    let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: userProfileImageUrl)
    print(userProfileImageUrl)
    storageRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (imageData, error) in
        let profileImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
        userImage = profileImage!
        self.userImage.image = profileImage
    })
    completion(userImage)
}
```

> For Username put other line in completion block of loadMembers4()

```
    func loadMembers4(completion: @escaping ([User]) -> ()) {
    var usersArray = [User]()
    ref.child("members").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for item in snapshot.children {
            if let snap = item as? FIRDataSnapshot {
                if let value = snap.value as? [String : Any] {
                    let birthday = value["birthday"] as! Int
                    let childParent = value["childParent"] as! String
                    let firstName = value["firstName"] as! String
                    let gender = value["gender"] as! String
                    let passcode = value["passcode"] as! Int
                    let profileImageUrl = value["profileImageUrl"] as! String

                    // get image

                    self.loadMemberProfilePict4(userProfileImageUrl: profileImageUrl, completion: { (userImage) in
                        let user = User(profilePhoto: userImage, userFirstName: firstName, userBirthday: birthday, userPasscode: passcode, userGender: gender, isUserChildOrParent: childParent)
                        **self.currentUserName = user.firstName**
                        self.instructionsLabel.text = "Choose daily and weekly job assignments for \(user.firstName)."
                        usersArray.append(user)
                        usersArray.sort(by: {$0.birthday > $1.birthday})
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        completion(usersArray)
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it doesn't work. By putting the `userName` and image into the `loadMemberProfilePict` method, the image on the screen just quickly cycles through all the user profile picts and lands on a random one every time. True, there is now an image there, but it's the wrong one. The reason it cycles through all the user profile images is because the function itself is part of a `for..in` loop.

Comment: Yes that is the problem, Because your code is in for loop and this methods are asynchronously called so your first user data fetching is still in queue and data fetching for second user is start. This is the reason for randomness in images.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Just talking it through gives me ideas to try. As for your comment about the `for...in` loop, yes, any ideas on how to get past that?

Comment: Simple solution, As  i see you are using "Storage location" property to get image from storage. Instead you can use "Download URL" to get image. So you don't have to fetch storage location to get image.

Comment: Open image in firebase , On right side you can see that Download URL property. So your whole loadMemberProfilePict4() can be replaced by one line.

Comment: Oh, I like that. I'll take a look and get back with you.

Comment: Okay, so how do I access the DownloadURL property from code?

Comment: when you upload image you have used this method:

storageRef.child("Customer").child(filePath)
            .putData(imageData, metadata: metadata) { [weak self] (metadata, error) in

you can use below line to get DownloadURL

"metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString"

Comment: Yes. I followed Firebase's guides for uploading the images as well as for downloading them. As I posted in my answer, I think the real issue is that I'm not able to call an escaping closure within another escaping closure. It may be a limitation of the software. I don't know. See my answer below for how I resolved the issue. And thank you so much for your help! Your ideas pushed me towards finding the solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

This is why your code is blank:

```
// #1
var userImage = UIImage()
// #2
storageRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (imageData, error) in
    // #4
    let profileImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
    userImage = profileImage!
})
// #3
completion(userImage)
```

There's a race condition because downloading the data is asynchronous. This means you return the empty image before the image has been downloaded. Fixing it by doing:

```
// #1
var userImage = UIImage()
// #2
storageRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (imageData, error) in
    // #3
    completion(UIImage(data: imageData!))
})
```

Should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I thought that, too, because that would make sense. But when I implement your code, I get an error: `fatal error: Index out of range`. Thoughts?

Comment: It seems to me that I can't call an escaping completion within an escaping completion. I don't know why. Perhaps there's another way to go about it? I have tried everything I can think of. Maybe you have some ideas you can throw my way?

Comment: The error is: `fatal error: Index out of range` in `ViewDidLoad` on line `self.currentUserName = usersArray[1].firstName`. If the code compiled properly, there should be four users, and the call for user [1] should not be out of range. And when I print `usersArray.count`, I get back a count of 4. So I know the array index is not out of range...